# Chrome cuts long page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

I'm working on a website that can load extra content when scrolling down.
Everything is working fine, until you scroll too far down in Chrome.

The content loads fine, as I can see everything in Developer Tools, but it is not visible. At some point, around 6000px down, the content disappears and the background color of the page is shown. 
[Image 1: The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91fhH.png)
[Image 2: Content is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDoxe.png)

If I hover my cursor over where the content should be, I can interact with it, also indicating that it is actually loading properly. This only happens in Chrome, both on Mac OS and Windows. I've tried Edge, Firefox, Safari and those work. Chrome Canary has the same problem.
Is this a bug in Chrome or am I doing something wrong that I'm missing?

---

Solution:

I've found a solution for the problem.

My page has an animation to fade in the content after loading. That was the cause of the problem. When I removed the animation from the div, specifically animation-fill-mode: forwards;, the page worked perfectly.

Comment: Hello Tim, Generally it is hard to help out any user who does not post code when asking a specific question about the code they have written. It is suggested you post as much code/pictures/fiddles/codepens with your question so that users are more likely to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Tim, and welcome to stackoverflow. It's difficult to solve a problem from screenshots, especially screenshots alone. To add to what Julian said, I would advise prioritising including code over screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for the problem.

My page has an animation to fade in the content after loading. That was the cause of the problem.
When I removed the animation from the div, specifically `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`, the page worked perfectly.